# Make td containing normal text as wide as if it was bold

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a html table. To increase the readability, I want the current row to be bold. I do that like that:

`.displayTable tr:hover
    {
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }`

But the table cells change their width and the whole table resizes when I hover rows with content filling the whole cell (because bolded text takes up more space). So how can I prevent this by making the cell as wide as if it was bold without acually making t bold?

Comment: that usually will be the case. You can try to give each cell a breathing room by defining their `width` and `height`.

Comment: So does that mean there isn't any clean possibility that won't use up any unnecassary space because the name of the strings can greatly differ (from 5 to 100 chars) and I don't know if the longest string in the table is 10 chars or 100 long

Comment: does it really need to be a table?

Comment: Yes. It displays data and isn't used for formatting reasons only (I'd use css for formatting for sure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could give a like-bold style using a `text-shadow` effect, e.g.

```
td:hover {
  text-shadow:  0 0 1px #999;  
}
```

so it won't affect the width of the text. Example code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cEqJK

Comment: nice. never thought about this :)

Comment: for IE : filter: glow(color=black,strength=5);  adjust the strength and color to your own need

Comment: Not quite what I though about, but after checking it out, I is vene better than what I had thought about initially, because the text doesn't jump any longer anyhow what increases the readability!

Comment: @user2241553 and picking specific values you could emulate different effects like letterpress, embossed... not only a simple bold: see http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-7-great-css-based-text-effects-using-the-text-shadow-property_2011-03-03.html

Comment: Not quit what was the task (I guess the people in the support for whose I made that table won't like that too much, but interesting link anyway. I'll bookmark it!)

Comment: The cure is worse than the disease: you would switch from using proper, typographer-designed bold face font to using algorithmic pseudo-bolding that makes strokes a bit thicker – and blurry.

Comment: Great solution. Setting the blur radius to `0` instead of `1px` makes the font appear bold.  `1px` will give blurred edges to the font.  `text-shadow: 0 0 0 #999`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is an ideal HTML/CSS solution for this problem, so I used some JavaScript to solve it.

The result can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjsum/5FnXx/1/).

HTML:

```
<table class="displayTable">
    <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.displayTable {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.displayTable td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.displayTable tr:hover { color: #000000; font-weight: bold; }
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var td = $(".displayTable tr td");

    td.css("font-weight", "bold");

    td.each( function () {
        var width = $(this).width(),
            height = $(this).height();
        $(this).css("width", width+"px");
        $(this).css("height", height+"px");
    });

    td.css("font-weight", "");
});
```

In my code, on page load the JavaScript essentially sets the font-weight to bold, checks to see what the width and height of the `td` elements are, and sets their width and height properties to those values, and then removes the font-weight property so that it goes back to whatever (if anything) the stylesheet sets for it. This should work.

Comment: Please note that my code currently assumes you only have one table. I will edit it to support multiple tables.

Comment: The table still resizes horizontal. That's not as bad, but still not optimal

Comment: It does not resize horizontally for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Ops, my mistake. I meant vertically.

Comment: Okay. I just updated it. I believe it should prevent both horizontal and vertical resizing now.

Comment: There is no HTML/CSS solution. A JavaScript-based approach like this is the only way. (But the problem is best avoided by not wanting to use bolding on hover – there are other highlighting methods, like backgrounds, that do not increase the width of text.)

Answer (score 0):

Make your table size static. Add `width` and `height` to `<td>`.

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmQjS/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="displayTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Word</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Word</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.displayTable tr:hover {
     color: #000000; 
    font-weight: bold;    
}
tr{ background:yellow; }
td{
     width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i tried to put in mind that your text that will be populated in each `td` would be long and short. So for that i use a separate `div` to bind the text and set their `overflow` with the basis of the `width and height` of your `td`

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    overflow-y:scroll;

}
td{
    padding:5px;
}

tr:hover{

    font-weight:bolder;
    color:red;
}
```

here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ8H3/2/)